# IOS Changing Main Bundle preference in XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, resourcebundle

I have a custom Resource bundle where i'll have all my images and localization files inside it.

When I assign some images in xib I have to type the entire path where image resides inside my bundle for example MyResource.bundle/Images/Event/xxx.png.

Which means in xib it always taking apps main bundle for images.

Here my question is is there any possibility is there like I can change the default bundle preference  to MyResource.bundle/Images So that I can see the image in xib when assigning to a uiimageView or any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preference? in simple words its not possible because there is no property like that, so you need to find out a way to achieve this, but i have used bundle for resources but not have this kinda problem because bundle is logical path

Comment: If you added a custom bundle in your project In XIB you need to specify complete path as I mentioned above to display image. So that in run time it will pick that corresponding image and it will display.

Comment: There is a solution with using the bundle, check here http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/05/resource-bundles/

Answer (score 0):

My solution is add one image manager to manage your image resource. I mean when you need an image, you just call your manager's method passing in the image name. And your image manager will read the correct image file from corresponding bundle and return it based on device's language.

Comment: thanks. But thats not my problem here. The xib should display the image which is inside my custom bundle.

Comment: @nik No xib is not smart enough to support different bundle. You need to use code to control it.